# A question probability involving maximum

Tags: probability

I want to calculate below probability

$$\mathbb{P} \left(MIN \left[X,1 \right] \leq y \right)$$

I have found below expression for above probability

$$\mathbb{P}(X \leqslant y) \cdot \mathbb{I}(y \leqslant 1) + \mathbb{I}(y > 1)$$

How can I intuitively understand the above derivation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $\min(x,y)>z$ if and only if both $x>z$ and $y>z$. Now we can use this to derive the CDF of the minimum: $$\mathbb P[\min(X,1)\leq y] = 1-\mathbb P[\min(X,1)>y]=1-\mathbb P[X>y, 1>y]$$ Note that this probability clearly is equal to $1$ if $y> 1$.

Otherwise, if $y\leq 1$ this probability equals $$1-\mathbb P[X>y]=\mathbb P[X\leq y]$$

If we write $\mathbb I(y\leq 1)$ for the indicator function $$\mathbb I(y\leq 1)=\begin{cases}1,&y\leq 1\\0,&y>1\end{cases}$$ we get $$\mathbb P[\min(X,1)\leq y]=\mathbb P[X\leq y]\cdot\mathbb I(y\leq 1)+ \mathbb I(y>1)$$ or in simple terms: If $y>1$ then the probability of this event is equal to $1$, otherwise, in the case of $y\leq 1$, the probability is equal to $\mathbb P[X\leq y]$.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an intuitive interpretation, per se. I can explain you how you can derive such an equality. Whenever $y > 1$ the condition $\min(1,X) \leq y$ is always true. Therefore, when $y > 1$,$\mathbb{P(\min(1,X) \leq y) = 1} = 1(y > 1) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq y)1(y \leq 1) + 1(y>1)$, because $1(y \leq 1) = 0$. Whenever $y \leq 1$, the condition $\min(1,X) \leq y$ is only true iff $X \leq y$, because $\min(1, X) \leq 1$ independently of $X$. Thus, when $y \leq 1$, we have that $\mathbb{P}(\min(1,X)\leq y) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq y) =  \mathbb{P}(X \leq y)1(y \leq1) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq y)1(y \leq1) + 1(y >1)$, since $1(y > 1) = 0$. Thus, for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that  $\mathbb{P}(\min(1,X)\leq y) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq y)1(y \leq1) + 1(y >1)$.